# Using checkboxes to show and hide sheets with apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox

I would like to use 5 checkboxes to hide (false) and show (true) sheets. I have the impression that this is not possible with onEdit. Can someone help me how I can solve this. Thank you very much for the help. GJM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const name = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
  if (name != 'Sheet1') return; // name of the first sheet
  const col = e.range.columnStart;
  if (col != 1) return;
  const row = e.range.rowStart;
  const value = e.range.getValue();
  const sheet = e.source.getSheets()[row]; // row1 is sheet[1], row2 is sheet[2], etc
  const _ = (value) ? sheet.showSheet() : sheet.hideSheet();
}
```

[image]

[image]

**Updated version**

Show/hide sheets by its names you can this way:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const name = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
  if (name != 'Sheet1') return;
  const col = e.range.columnStart;
  if (col != 1) return;
  const value = e.range.getValue();
  const name_to_hide = e.range.offset(0,1).getValue(); // get a name
  const sheet = e.source.getSheetByName(name_to_hide);
  const _ = (value) ? sheet.showSheet() : sheet.hideSheet();
}
```

It takes a name from the next column ('B' in this case), and show/hides a sheet with this name.

Or you can use solution of Dmitry Kostyuk if you don't want show sheet names in column 'B'. That way you can wire the names inside a script.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It functions. But it is also possible to show tabs with a specific name. For example "Dashboard", "Import" etc. GJM

Comment: It's possible of course. I just updated my answer.

Comment: Big thanks Yuri. It functions. For me now the assignment to figure out how things work. For a novice user of Apps Sript a big challenge. Gert-Jan.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  const targetRange =  '{"columnEnd":1,"columnStart":1,"rowEnd":1,"rowStart":1}';
  if (JSON.stringify(e.range) !== targetRange) return; // validate that the right checkbox is checked
  if(e.value === 'TRUE') return sheet.hideSheet();
  return sheet.showSheet();
}
```

Make sure your trigger is properly set up though. And likely you want to do better range validation that I did, but that's just for demo purposes :)

Comment: It will hide a current sheet! Along with the checkbox(es). Does it make sense?

Comment: It will hide the sheet you define, that's why the `getSheetByName()` is there